# How to change default font opening CSV in Excel

Tags: templates, csv, excel-2010

I'm using Excel 2010 to edit CSV files.  Just for aesthetic reasons, I'd like to have it use the Courier New font as the default instead of Calibri.  I've found the process to create a book.xlt which becomes the default template for opening a **new** spreadsheet, but is there any way to create a template that will be referenced/applied when opening an existing CSV file?